# Proving the Grassmannian is a manifold

Tags: manifolds, grassmannian

The *Grassmannian* $\mathrm{Gr}(k, V)$ is the space of all $k$-dimensional subspaces of a (real or complex) vector space $V$. I am interested in the following strategy of proving $\mathrm{Gr}(k, V)$ is a manifold.

Let us suppose that $V$ has the structure of an inner product space. Then each subspace $W \subseteq V$ can be uniquely identified with the orthogonal projection $P : V \to V$ whose image is $W$. Hence, we can view $\mathrm{Gr}(k, V)$ as the space of orthogonal projections
$$
\mathrm{Gr}(k, V) = \{P : V \to V \mid P^2 = P, P^* = P\}.
$$
The first condition $P^2 = P$ ensures $P$ is a projection, and the second condition $P^* = P$ ensures $P$ is orthonormally diagonalizable.

With this formulation, we see that $\mathrm{Gr}(k, V)$ can be viewed as the preimage of $0$ under the map $F : \mathrm{Sym}_n \to \mathrm{Sym}_n$ given by
$$
F(A) = A^2 - A,
$$
where $\mathrm{Sym}_n$ is the set of self-adjoint matrices. In particular, if the differential $dF$ had constant rank near $\mathrm{Gr}(k, V)$, then it would follow automatically that $\mathrm{Gr}(k, V)$ has the structure of a smooth manifold.

It is easy to show that $dF : \mathrm{Sym}_n \to \mathrm{Sym}_n$ is given by
$$
dF(B) = AB + BA - B.
$$
However, I'm not sure how to find the rank of $dF$. Does anyone know how I might proceed? Or is this not an effective strategy of showing that the Grassmannian is a manifold?

Comment: What do you wish to prove? That it is a projective manifold or a smooth manifold?

Comment: Also The Grassmanian can be seen as the space of orbits of the action of $\operatorname{GL}_k (F) $ on the spaces of matrices of size $n \times k$ of rank $k$, maybe this could help. Here $F = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace I'm trying to prove that it is a smooth manifold. I am aware of other ways of proving that the Grassmannian is a smooth manifold; I'm just interested in whether this particular method would work.

Comment: Ok nice idea then! But you don't ensure the rank of the grassmanian here? You should add $\dim \ker (id - p) = k$ or am I mistaken?